# Xamarin Shell Raise Ambiguous Routes matched Exception - [0:] Shell: Failed to Navigate Back:

Tags: xamarin.forms, c#-4.0

In Xamari.Forms, I use the following route declaration in AppShell.xaml.cs :

```
routes.Add("DSKhachHangHalf", typeof(DanhSachKHHalf));
routes.Add("chiTietHalf", typeof(ChiTietKHHalf));
routes.Add("rvatTu", typeof(vatTu));
```

I then navigate  : DanhSachKHHalf -> ChiTietKHHalf -> rvatTu

In DanhSachKHHalf.cs i call ChiTietKHHalf with code :

```
await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"chiTietHalf");
```

In ChiTietKHHalf.cs i call vatTu with code :

```
await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"rvatTu");
```

or

```
await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"/chiTietHalf/rvatTu");
```

or

```
await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"DSKhachHangHalf/chiTietHalf/rvatTu");
```

when i go back to the page from vatTu to ChiTietKHHalf But I get this exception :

> [0:] Shell: Failed to Navigate Back: System.ArgumentException:
> Ambiguous routes matched for:
> //D_FAULT_FlyoutItem10/IMPL_DSKhachHangHalf/DSKhachHangHalf/chiTietHalf
> matches found:
> //D_FAULT_FlyoutItem10/IMPL_DSKhachHangHalf/DSKhachHangHalf/chiTietHalf,//D_FAULT_FlyoutItem10/IMPL_DSKhachHangHalf/DSKhachHangHalf/chiTietHalf
> Parameter name: uri

Comment: Are there any `Route` attributes in `AppShell.xaml`? The only way I know to get an ambiguous route is if that Route is declared two different places. This could happen if both `.xaml` and `.xaml.cs` declare the same Route.

Comment: That's good! It might be helpful to others to add Your Answer below, explaining what the problem was, and how you  solved it.

Comment: Have you got solution? I'm getting same error